# Django - Get objects that don't have one to to one attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a concept where there is a model that has a `OneToOne` field with `User`. How can I query for all users that are not assigned to one of these?

For example:

```
class SpecialUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Not all users are special users. How can I get all users that are not special users using `objects` (ie: `User.objects.filter(something)`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
User.objects.filter(specialuser=None)
```

Or:

```
User.objects.filter(specialuser__isnull=True)
```

You can provide `related_name` to make it more readable or to avoid pottential collisions. Example:

```
class SpecialUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="special_user_profile")
```

In this case, you'd use the related name instead:

```
User.objects.filter(special_user_profile=None)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great

Comment: @SamCreamer hi, would you consider accepting this answer if it resolved and answered your question ?